# close mdi active child using keyboard escape key

Tags: c#, .net

I need to close active mdi child form using keyboard escape key. Following code closes active child but throws exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object).

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape && this.ActiveMdiChild != null) //close child
    {
        this.ActiveMdiChild.Close();
    }
    else if (keyData == Keys.Escape) //exit app
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    else if (keyData == Keys.Insert) //open add form
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

What I need to change ?
thanks

Comment: same ex if I try to close all children with code :        `private void closeAllChilds()
        { 
            foreach (Form child in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                child.Close();
            }
        
        }`

Comment: Where exactly does the exception happen? I would assume that you do something wrong in your OnClosing() or OnClosed() callbacks. Also, you should probably add an else before the return, because you don't want the key to be handled again.

Comment: this closeChild code works as button, but not when esc key is pressed

Comment: You *must* return **true** when you've used the keystroke.

Comment: @CarloŠtefanac: That's a completely unrelated piece of code. You're probably using some controls in your form that you're not disposing of properly. Or you fail to deregister events.

Comment: @Hans Passant When I return true; it works.Thanks